# Different output for recliner power supply safe to use 25V 2.5A to a 29V 2A

Tags: power-supply, voltage, amperage, output, input

My father broke his power supply for his recliner. He's on oxygen 24/7 and I was trying to find out if it was safe to use a slightly different power supply cause I can't find an exact match. The one he broke says it's input is 100-240V and output is 25V,2.5A. I can only find ones that have the output slightly different saying 24-29V, 2A or 29V, 2A. Not sure if that .5 is a big deal or weather it wouldn't work or most of all if it was unsafe being he's in his 70's and on oxygen 24/7. I wanna make him as comfortable as possible and get him back in his beloved recliner lol but didn't want to waste my time if it wouldn't work or risk his safety before buying one and leaving it plug in with him. Any help is much appreciated and thank you in advance for taking the time to read this and answer. Theres a pic of the old broken one attached also. [image]

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to replace the adapter with one that has the same voltage and at least the same current.  If the replacement adapter has a higher current rating, that's fine and I actually recommend it.  Since the load is presumably a motor, which has a pretty high starting current, some adapters that may be rated for 2.5A continuous current might not work, especially if the recliner's control circuitry doesn't manage the starting current well.  A too-small adapter could either drop the output voltage low enough to cause problems during the starting surge or even go into an overcurrent protection mode and turn the output off entirely.